# Mysterious file appeared on Desktop

Tags: permissions, files, symbolic-link

While browsing the Internet I suddenly came across this file on my desktop. I tried finding out what was in the file but found that I did not have permission to open it.

Can anyone help out?

[image: Picture related]

Comment: Open a terminal, and run `ls -blh ~/Desktop`, then add the output here, please.

Comment: `total 12K
-rw-rw-r-- 1 john john 196 Nov  6 06:10 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ deadmau5\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ .desktop`

This is the output muru

Comment: Like @Artyom answered you dragged and dropped a URL from the Location bar or a link to the desktop. You can just delete that file.

Comment: I had no idea were the file had come from. Will mark it answered asap. Thanks RoVo!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a youtube link. https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYEK6xds6eo-3tr4xRdflmQ

You accidentally dragged the address bar on your desktop while browsing the link or a page that has the link, your internet browser created a shortcut to the address.

Comment: Haha! There was me thinking "How the hell did this file appear". Thanks Artyom!